# Access to fetch `url` been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. ReactJS

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, google-cloud-functions, fetch-api

I'm am trying to fetch a serverless function from a react app in development mode with the following code.

```
let response = await fetch(url,
       {
           method: 'POST',
           mode: 'cors',
           body: "param=" + paramVar,
        })
        .then(response => response.json());
```

The backend function is a Python Cloud function with the following code:

```
def main(request):
    # CORS handling
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        # Allows GET requests from any origin with the Content-Type
        # header and caches preflight response for an 3600s
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600'
        }

        return ('', 204, headers)
    
    # Set CORS headers for the main request
    headers = {
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    }

    # Process request
    return (json.dumps(response), 200, headers)
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
Access to fetch at 'url' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

When I try to perform the same request using curl I get a proper response. Using curl to get the options gives me the following:

```
HTTP/2 204
access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-max-age: 3600
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Sun, 16 Aug 2020 01:29:41 GMT
```

Anyone can help me understand why I'm not able to get a response at my front-end? The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is present in the headers so I really don't understand what is the cause of this error.

Comment: `Should allow OPTIONS method` - doesn't the code do that @charlietfl ... `if request.method == 'OPTIONS'`

Comment: This issue can occur due to different causes. Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43881141/11928130), it may help you troubleshooting your issue.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There was actually a bug in the backend that was only triggered by some additional headers added by the browser. In that particular case, the server was returning a 404 error which wouldn't contain my header definitions and would cause the CORS policy block.

I was only able to identify the bug after I used devtools to track the request sent by the browser and replicated all the headers in my curl request. After fixing the function logic the problem was fixed.

Comment: Um, since these posts are supposed to be here to help the whole community, can you please describe in more detail exactly how (which headers?) you solved this and provide code samples?

Answer (score 4):

Install the CORS package in the backend.
Then open your server.js file or whatever is yours.
Then import it to the file

```
const cors = require('cors');
```

And then use it

```
app.use(cors());
```

reload the browser and should be done!

Comment: Asked question is for python backend..

Answer (score 0):

This is my first post at Stack

I saw OP's response and I think I know what they meant - as I ran into the same problem myself.

Basically when you send a request to 'url', if that URL didn't reply with a successful response, then it will send you a 'bad response', in my case, a "503".
A "503" response is still a response, but this response would not contain the access-control-allow-origin header, so the browser (dutifully) replied that it will not accept this - even if it's garbage anyway!

Hope that might be helpful to someone else ...
Cheers

Answer (score -1):

add content-type header to your fetch method in the frontend and try again:

```
let response = await fetch(url,
       {
           method: 'POST',
           mode: 'cors',
           body: "param=" + paramVar,
           headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'application/json'
       },
  }).then(response => response.json());
```

Comment: Asked question is for python backend..